# After doing a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.10 my USB Keyboard and mouse won't work

Tags: keyboard, mouse, 13.10

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.10, and when i tried to log in after the restart, my USB keyboard wouldn't turn on/register so I can't log in. Is there any way to fix this problem, or should I just say screw it and go back to 13.04? My keyboard worked when my computer was on 13.04, as did my mouse.

Comment: Silly question, but are you plugged into a USB3 port? Unplug der maus und keyboard und put them in a different post, does that help?

Comment: Didn't work. Also tried unplugging the machine and letting it set for 30 seconds and that still didn't work.

Comment: I had a problem with identical symptoms. This thread on whirlpool (http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/forum-replies.cfm?t=2170773) has some suggestions -- particularly post #2 referencing http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1264128 -- but I'd already dropped back to 13.04 and haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Note: This is reported as a bug on Launchpad with even the latest 14.04 daily images: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1244176 .